# PHP multi select quote script

Tags: php, forms, input, multi-select

I did something like this :

**devis2.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="quote_validation2.js"></script>
<?php
$ddcount = 1;
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $$key = $value;
}
If (isset($_POST['garment_type']) && $ddcount == 1) {
    $post_to = "devis2-resultats.php";
    $ddcount = $ddcount + 1;
} Else {
    $post_to = "devis2.php";
}
?>
<div style="float:right; display: block;"><a href="devis2.php"><img style="border: none;" border="0" src="images/quote-again.gif" width="120" height="16" /></a></div><br/><br/>
<form  name="instantquote" onSubmit="return validator(this)" method="post" action="<?php echo $post_to; ?>">
        Au bac:<br/><select  multiple size="3" name="garment_type" class="quoteFields" tabindex="1">
<?php
If (isset($_POST['garment_type'])) {
    echo "<option value=\"$garment_type\" selected>$garment_type</option> \n";
} Else {
    echo "<option value=\"0\" selected>Choisir un soin</option> \n";
}
?>              
                <option value="soin1">soin1</option>
                <option value="soin2">soin2</option>
                    </select><br/>Longueur des cheveux*:<br/>
                <select  name="colors_back" class="quoteFields" tabindex="5" size="1" onChange="Javascript:document.instantquote.submit()" >
<?php
If (isset($_POST['colors_back'])) {
    echo "<option value=\"$colors_back\" selected>$colors_back</option> \n";
} Else {
    echo "<option value=\"0\" selected>Choisir une longueur</option> \n";
}
?>
                <option value="+ de 25 cm">+ de 25 cm</option>
                <option value="- de 25 cm">- de 25 cm</option>
                </select> 
                <input type="hidden" name="ddcount" value="<?php echo $ddcount; ?>">

            <br/><br/><input type="submit" value="Obtenir votre devis" name="quote" class="quoteSubmit" tabindex="20">

</form>
```

**devis2-resultats.php**

```
<?php
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $$key = $value;
}
include("quote-prices2.php");
?>

<br/><br/><b>Au bac:</b> <?php echo $garment_type; ?><br/><br/>
<?php
            If (!isset($_POST['ind_numbers'])) {
            } Else {
            ?>
Individual Numbers:<?php echo $ind_numbers; ?><br/><br/>
            <?php
            }
            If (!isset($_POST['ind_names'])) {
            } Else {
            ?>
Individual Names: <?php echo $ind_names; ?><br/><br/>

            <?php
            }
            If (!empty($email)) { ?>
<br/><br/><b>Envoyé à:</b> <?php echo $email; ?><br/><br/>
            <?php
            }
            ?>          

<br/><br/><div style="font-size:16px; background-color:#fff; color:#bf3d71;"> <b>Total:</b> <?php $dectotal = sprintf('%0.2f', $total); echo $dectotal;  ?> $</div><br/><br/><br>
```

**quote-prices2.php**

```
<?php
// INCOMING VARIABLES FOR PROCESSING:  garment_type, garment_color, quantity, colors_front, colors_back, ind_numbers, ind_names

// GARMENT TYPE PRICE

$flash_charge = 0;

switch ($garment_type)    {
  case "soin1":
    $price_garment_type = 6.00;
    break;
  case "soin2":
    $price_garment_typea = 7.00;
    break;

}

if ($_POST['garment_type'] === 'soin2') {
switch ($colors_back)    {

    case "+ de 25 cm":
    $price_garment_typea = $price_garment_typea + 50;
    break;

}}
$total_garment_pricing = $price_garment_type + $price_garment_typea;
$total_additionals    = $total_garment_pricing;

$total = $total_garment_pricing + $total_additionals;
$per_garment_price = $total/2;
$total = $total/2;

?>
                                        **quote_validation2.js**



   function validator(form) { 

        if (form.colors_back.value == 0) {
        alert("Vous devez sélectionner une longueur de cheveux.");
        return false;
      }

    return true; 
    }

    function CalcKeyCode(aChar) {
      var character = aChar.substring(0,1);
      var code = aChar.charCodeAt(0);
      return code;
    }

    function checkNumber(val) {
      var strPass = val.value;
      var strLength = strPass.length;
      var lchar = val.value.charAt((strLength) - 1);
      var cCode = CalcKeyCode(lchar);

      /* Check if the keyed in character is a number
         do you want alphabetic UPPERCASE only ?
         or lower case only just check their respective
         codes and replace the 48 and 57 */

      if (cCode < 48 || cCode > 57 ) {
        var myNumber = val.value.substring(0, (strLength) - 1);
        val.value = myNumber;
      }
      return false;
    }
```

I'am very bad at php developement. At this point if I select `soin1 & soin2` it display one price only. `soin1 = 6 & soin2 = 7` if they are both selected I'd like to obtain 13 as a result. And of course if soin1,soin2 & + de 25 cm are selected I'd like to obtain 63 as a result. The question is how can I make multi select work to obtain the addition of `soin1 & soin2`. See the script [here](http://www.herveou-coiffure.com/devis2.php).

Comment: What is `soin1,soin2 & + de 25 cm`?

Comment: So, what have you tried .....

Comment: http://www.herveou-coiffure.com/devis2.php

Comment: The thing is i don't know what to try...

Comment: @user1758935 - then we also don't want to try!